# how to build a IOS style list with listview builder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, flutter-cupertino

I was wondering how to build a Cupertino list like that, with a `listView.builder`
I did it with the CupertinoFormSection, but when i add the `listView.builder` inside the form, the list does not show. So, right now i put the CupertinoFormSection after the listView, but the result is not what I want.

[image: desired UI]

**This is my code:**

```
body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: entries.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() async {
                index = i;
                if (i == 0){
                  await context.setLocale(Locale('en','US'));
                }
                else if (i == 1){
                  await context.setLocale(Locale('fr','FR'));
                }
                else {
                  await context.setLocale(Locale('it','IT'));
                }
              });
            },
            child: CupertinoFormSection(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children:[
                      Text(entries[i]),
                      index == i
                          ? Icon(Icons.check_outlined, color: Colors.blue,)
                          : Icon(null),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

**This is the output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the standard widgets [`CupertinoFormSection`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoFormSection-class.html) and the [`CupertinoFormRow`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoFormRow-class.html). They are made specific for this kind of UI.

Check it out (also the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4605682fd9cc3a2065bc32cca923f0dd)).

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class Item {
  final String prefix;
  final String? helper;
  const Item({required this.prefix, this.helper});
}

const items = [
  Item(prefix: 'Italiano', helper: 'Italiano'),
  Item(prefix: 'English (US)', helper: 'Inglese (USA)'),
  Item(prefix: 'Español (EE. UU.)', helper: 'Spagnolo (USA)'),
  Item(prefix: 'Italiano (Italia)', helper: 'Italiano (Italia)'),
  Item(prefix: 'Italiano (Svizzera)', helper: 'Italiano (Svizzera)'),
  Item(prefix: 'English', helper: 'Inglese'),
];

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Container(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 242, 242, 247),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 250,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: CupertinoFormSection.insetGrouped(
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    items.length,
                    (index) => GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
                      child: buildCupertinoFormRow(
                        items[index].prefix,
                        items[index].helper,
                        selected: _selectedIndex == index,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildCupertinoFormRow(
    String prefix,
    String? helper, {
    bool selected = false,
  }) {
    return CupertinoFormRow(
      prefix: Text(prefix),
      helper: helper != null
          ? Text(
              helper,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
            )
          : null,
      child: selected
          ? const Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.check_mark,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 118, 234),
              size: 20,
            )
          : Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great it worked out! I just need to change background color and add media query to the container.